# LibGDX: how do I multiply vector with scalar without modifing original vector? (simple gravity system in Java game)

Tags: java, vector, libgdx, gravity, scalar

I am currently implementing a simple gravity system in my game using LibGDX. However, I found that the way you multiply vectors with vectors and vectors with scalars is a bit different.

In Unity, I would implement gravity like this:

```
    public Vector3 velocity;
    public Vector3 acceleration;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.position += velocity*Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        Vector3 force = Physics.gravity*GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass;
        acceleration = force/GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass;

        velocity = velocity + acceleration*Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
}
```

Vector multiplication is very straight forward.

In LibGDX, I am trying the following:

```
    import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

    final protected Vector2 _gravity = new Vector2(0f, -9.82f);
    final protected float _mass = 1f;
    protected Vector2 _velocity;
    protected Vector2 _acceleration;

    public void Update(float deltaTime)
    {
        // Transform is a class containing a Vector2 called Position
        Transform.Position.add(_velocity.scl(deltaTime));

        Vector2 force = _gravity.scl(_mass);
        _acceleration = force.scl(1f/_mass);    
        _velocity = _velocity.add(_acceleration.scl(deltaTime));

        System.out.println(_velocity);
        // _velocity gets smaller and smaller and finally hits 0.
    }
```

This does not work, since the *scl()* method of Vector2 directly changes the vector itself, as can be seen in the Vector2 class of LibGDX:

```
public Vector2 scl (float scalar) {
        x *= scalar;
        y *= scalar;
        return this;
    }
```

I assume I want it to return a *new* Vector2, instead of changing the vector itself directly.

How can I do that? Or am I completely wrong? Is there an easier way in LibGDX to multiply vectors with scalars using the "*" operator?

Comment: The reason you can't do it the Unity way is that Java doesn't have structs. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that method (and others) don't create a new vector is to avoid creating garbage. Creating garbage will cause the garbage collector to clean up, which can (and will) cause hick ups. For games, frequent hick-ups is something you typically want to avoid.

So, if it is something you only need to once, then it is okay to use the `cpy()` method or `new` keyword. But for frequently called methods (like your update method), you really want to avoid that. Instead you can use a member vector.

```
final Vector2 force = new Vector2();
public void update(float delta) {
    ...
    force.set(_gravity).scl(mass);
    ...
}
```

Note that for operations like `position += velocity * time` you can use the `mulAdd` method.

```
position.mulAdd(velocity, deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Vector2 force = _gravity.cpy().scl(_mass);`

The `cpy()` method returns a copy of the vector, thus you end up multiplying the copy with `_mass` rather than the original vector.

The slight advantage of this solution, compared to using `new Vector2()` to create the copy is that it works for any vector dimension without modification.

Answer (score 0):

You could try duplicating the vector before scaling it, like so:

```
new Vector2(_gravity).scl(_mass);
```